# how can get the value of SQLPATH key on local network

Tags: c#, sql-server, path, registry

I want to get the value of SQLPATH key in the registry of  the server's pc on local computer,can any user on local network get this value and how can i get this value???
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>microsoft>microsoft sql server>SQLEXPRESS>Setup>"
thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, SQLPATH is defined in a registry entry during installation.
For more information, look here.

- [Configuring SQL*Plus](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b12170/ch3.htm)

---

**EDIT :**

I guess, this will help you out : [SQL Server's database location](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Obtain-your-SQL-Server-s-database-location/0,339028455,320283099,00.htm).

Comment: i know this but how can read the value of this key on local network?